# Convert dict value to list and take average

Tags: python

I am trying to extract values from a certain dictionary key and take the average of those values. The output of my dictionary called scores looks like:

```
{
    'fit_time':       array([0.36260605, 0.36630321, 0.28634191, 0.29873514, 0.15965009]),
    'score_time':     array([0.02901483, 0.03418779, 0.03244114, 0.03267598, 0.01934624]),
    'test_acc':       array([0.83928571, 0.83928571, 0.81785714, 0.84464286, 0.83928571]),
    'train_acc':      array([0.90580357, 0.91071429, 0.90982143, 0.90625, 0.90758929]),
    'test_log_loss':  array([-0.38442156, -0.37268129, -0.37284406, -0.37891302, -0.43271307]),
    'train_log_loss': array([-0.23096467, -0.2320267, -0.23016542, -0.23322982, -0.22868747]),
    'test_recall':    array([0.32323232, 0.35353535, 0.27272727, 0.33333333, 0.23469388]),
     'train_recall':  array([0.55443038, 0.56962025, 0.54683544, 0.55696203, 0.55050505])
}
```

For example, for isolating the `test accuracy` I have this code:

```
accuracy.append(list(scores["test_acc"]))
```

which gives me:

```
[[0.8392857142857143, 0.8392857142857143, 0.8178571428571428, 0.8446428571428571, 0.8392857142857143]]
```

but then why I try to take the mean of this through `mean(accuracy)`, I get this error:

> TypeError: can't convert type 'list' to numerator/denominator

Any advice greatly appreciated!

Comment: `mean(scores['test_acc'])` or `mean(accuracy[0])`

Comment: What `accuracy` variable is ? And from which package `array` comes from ?

Comment: mean(accuracy[0]) works for you?

Comment: This is output from the cross_validate package.

Comment: Yes, it works - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the double [[, you can fix this by selecting the first array in the array,

```
import statistics

listOfAccuracy = [[0.8392857142857143, 0.8392857142857143, 0.8178571428571428, 0.8446428571428571, 0.8392857142857143]]

print(statistics.mean(listOfAccuracy[0]))
```

returns, `0.8360714285714286`

Comment: Ah thank you! Is there a way to preempt that when I originally select the accuracy items from the dictionary?

Comment: I am not able to test this as I can't see the definition of "array" or "accuracy" however try replacing, accuracy.append(list(scores["test_acc"])) with accuracy = list(scores["test_acc"])